# Leaflet open popup on mouse hover over list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, popup, leaflet

One view of my application is, a list of all the pins on the one side, and the map with the actual pins on the other side.

I would like the popups to open as I hover through the list with my mouse. Lets say my mouse is on #1 on the list I would like the popup of the corresponding pin to open.

this the html from the list component:

```
    <table class="table-striped">
      <thead>
        <!-- <th>id</th> -->
        <th>Kunstwerkname</th>
        <th>Strasse</th>
        <th>PLZ</th>
        <th>
          <button class="button-list" (click)="addArtwork()">
            <img src="assets/icons/add.svg">
          </button>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let artwork of artworkList;" class="artworkList" (mouseover)="previewPopup(artwork)">
          <td>{{artwork.name}}</td>
          <td>{{artwork.streetname}}</td>
          <td>{{artwork.zipcode}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="button-list" (click)="editArtwork(artwork)">
              <img src="assets/icons/edit.svg">
            </button>
            <button class="button-list" (click)="deleteArtwork(artwork)">
              <img src="assets/icons/delete.svg">
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

the ts of the list component:

```
import { Artwork, ArtworkService } from './../_services/artwork.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-artwork-list',
  templateUrl: './artwork-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artwork-list.component.css']
})
export class ArtworkListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() private add = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() private edit = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() private preview = new EventEmitter<number>();
  artworkList: Artwork[];

  constructor(
    private artworkService: ArtworkService,
) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refresh();
  }
  refresh() {
    this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then(
      artworkList => this.artworkList = artworkList
    );
  }

  addArtwork() {
    console.log('add artwork');
    this.add.emit();
  }

  editArtwork(artwork: Artwork) {
    console.log('edit artwork ' + artwork.name + ' ' + artwork.id );
    this.edit.emit(artwork.id);
  }

  deleteArtwork(artwork: Artwork) {
    console.log('delete artwork ' + artwork.name + ' ' + artwork.id );
    this.artworkService.delete(artwork.id).then(
      () => this.refresh()
    );
  }

  previewPopup(artwork: Artwork) {
    console.log("hovering mouse");
    console.log(artwork.id);
    this.preview.emit(artwork.id);
  }

}
```

and ts of the map component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

/*When you include the leaflet script inside the Angular project, it gets
loaded and exported into a L variable.*/
declare let L; //this is the leaflet variable!

import { MapButtonsComponent } from './map-buttons/map-buttons';
import { Artwork, ArtworkService } from '../_services/artwork.service';
import { FilterMapComponent } from './filter-map/filter-map.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-open-street-map',
  templateUrl: './open-street-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./open-street-map.component.css']
})
export class OpenStreetMapComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() private add = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() private edit = new EventEmitter<number>();
  artworkList: Artwork[];
  map;

  // markerIcon
  markerIcon = {
    icon: L.icon({
      iconSize: [25, 41],
      iconAnchor: [13, 16],
      iconUrl: 'assets/icons/marker.svg',
      shadowUrl: 'assets/icons/marker-shadow.png'
    })
  };

  constructor(
    private artworkService: ArtworkService,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [48.208, 16.373],
      zoom: 13,
      zoomControl: false,
    });

    this.refresh();

    // base layer
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 13,
      id: 'mapbox.streets',
      accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicHcxN2wwMDgiLCJhIjoiY2pua2c2OWxuMGVkOTNxbWh5MWNqajEwdyJ9.X_SuGwNGs12TwCsrsUvBxw'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    MapButtonsComponent.renderZoom(this.map);
    MapButtonsComponent.renderCompass(this.map);
    MapButtonsComponent.renderLocation(this.map);
  }

  previewArtwork() {
   this.map.eachLayer(layer => {
  if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    this.map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
let previewedMarker = L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
  .addTo(this.map)
  .on('mouseover', () => {
    openPopup();
  });
}

  }
}
```

Comment: What about creating a directive?

Comment: Is it a leaflet question or angular ? Do you know how to do it just with leaflet ?

Comment: @YaFred I'm guessing the solution/problem includes a bit of both! Yes with leaflet its just a matter of adding 'mousover' instead of 'click' to open the popup, but that pertains specifically if the mouse is on the marker. What i am trying to achieve is that, the popups open as i over  the list on the left side of the screen. That is on the right is the map with the markers, on the left a list of the markers. I want that as i hover over the list, the corresponding markers open their popups. I hope i have articulated it to an understandable extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach could be considered. Lets assume the initial data for markers is represented in the following format:

```
locations = [
    {
      name: "Oslo",
      lat: 59.923043,
      lng: 10.752839
    },
    {
      name: "Stockholm",
      lat: 59.339025,
      lng: 18.065818
    },
    //..
  ];
```

Then for the given data markers on map could be initialized like this:

```
this.markers = this.locations.map(loc => {
    const marker = new L.marker({ lat: loc.lat, lng: loc.lng });
    marker.bindPopup(loc.name);
    marker.addTo(map);
    return marker;
});
```

Now comes the turn of communication between selector component and map itself, lets assume the following selector:

```
<ul>
  <li (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter(idx) "  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave(idx)"  *ngFor="let loc of locations; let idx = index">{{ loc.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

then the popup visibility could be controlled like this:

```
mouseEnter(selectedIndex) {
   const selectedMarker = this.markers[selectedIndex];
  selectedMarker.openPopup();
}

mouseLeave(selectedIndex) {
   const selectedMarker = this.markers[selectedIndex];
   selectedMarker.closePopup();
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhpgdv)

Comment: I keep getting the error "selectedMarker.openPopup is not a function", any ideas? i have adapted your solution abit to fit my application. This only difference, the index is passed from my list component to my map component, then passed onto the array of markers like you have done. But i keep getting that error and don't quite know how to proceed!

Comment: @kontenurban, i could only guess without seeing the actual code, but the error  could mean 1)`index` is not valid or  2)`this.markers[selectedIndex]` is not a marker object in your case

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mouseover` you have to listen to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

On `mouseenter` you will create a popup and place it on the map, on `mouseleave` you will close the popup

Example code with jQuery (my postContent equates to your artwork)

```
$("div.postContent").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
        var postId = $(this).attr("data-postId");

        tooltipPopup = L.popup();   
        var title = postlistByGlobalId[postId].title;
        tooltipPopup.setContent(title);
        tooltipPopup.setLatLng(markersByGlobalId[postId].getLatLng());
        tooltipPopup.openOn(map);

        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });

$("div.postContent").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        map.closePopup(tooltipPopup);
    });
```

To achieve that you need to give a unique id to all your artworks (postId in my example) and put your markers in an associative array `markersByGlobalId`

This could be useful: http://franceimage.github.io/map and http://franceimage.github.io/map-v1

My examples are monolitic (1 html, 1 js file). You will need some extra work to use it in your Angular app.